# Webkit Speech api - general questions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit, google-voice

I'm using webkit-speech on google chrome.
demo:https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

And I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I recognize when a person stop talking?
2. Is there a way to leave the microphone on for infinity? it turns grey after about 30 seconds silence, and i want it to work for infinity..
3. on this demo, there is not an "Allow button" when trying to speak, but on my website - i used the same code - every time i try to start using, it pops up a bar saying: "Allow" or "Disallow" for microphone input.
4. Is there a way to check "When user stopped talking" or something like that? (I now check "if text on the text box hasnt changed in the last 2 seconds", and that creates a lag between the command and the function execution)
5. is there a way to make this code viable on mobile? on mobile it says: "you need a version of chrome that is heigher than 25", and if I could make it viable for mobile, that would make my life easier..

Notes:

- Knowing how to fix "3" will fix 2, because if there is not "Allow", I can trigger a click.
- I'm not trying to spy on people, it is working locally so i can use vocal commands for my automated house.

Answer (score 1):

How to fix 3:
I guess that you are using HTTP protocol and not HTTPS.
If you will use HTTPS, the user will not need to "allow" each time, but only once in the used lifetime.
I too wander about all of the other 4, so if you figure it out, i'd love you to send me how.